# How to call static methods inside the same class in python

Tags: python

I have two static methods in the same class

```
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def methodA():
        print 'methodA'

    @staticmethod
    def methodB():
        print 'methodB'
```

How could I call the `methodA` inside the `methodB`? `self` seems to be unavailable in the static method.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In fact, the `self` is not available in static methods.
If the decoration `@classmethod` was used instead of `@staticmethod` the first parameter would be a reference to the class itself (usually named as `cls`).
But despite of all this, inside the static method `methodB()` you can access the static method `methodA()` directly through the class name:

```
@staticmethod
def methodB():
    print 'methodB'
    A.methodA()
```

Answer (score 9):

As @Ismael Infante says, you can use the `@classmethod` decorator.

```py
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def methodA():
        print 'methodA'

    @classmethod
    def methodB(cls):
        cls.methodA()
```

Comment: What is the difference/benefit of this vs. using @staticmethod and using the name of the class?

Comment: @JamesCarter if you use classmeethod, you get the cls variable, which refers to the containing class itself, so you can use this "cls" to refer to the class and its resources (method, attribute). If you use staticmethod, you can only use the class name to refer to the class, and if you are in a child class and inherit static method from parent class, the class name in the static method still remains the parent class name...

Answer (score 1):

```
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def methodA():
        print 'methodA'

    @staticmethod
    def methodB():
        print 'methodB'
        __class__.methodA()
```

Comment: +1 for a handy solution because explicitly naming a class when calling a static method within it isn't nice :)